# Name of human language related gene

Tags: human-genetics, gene, language

I'd like to know the name of a gene with the following description of effects:

- Humans having two copies of this gene with a certain mutation aren't able to acquire human language, but otherwise their intelligence is not depressed
- The human version of the gene differs significantly from the one found in the great apes
- The human version of the gene was transferred to mice, and it was reported that the "voice" and the communication of the so-manipulated mice differs from the one of "wild" mice
- If I remember correctly, the gene has the letter "x" in it like *hox* or *pox* or *pax* but alas, memory can be faulty

What is the name of this gene?

Bonus question: What are relevant publications concerning the gene described?

Comment: [FOXP2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOXP2)? Three scholarly hits and the appropriate wiki entry on first 4 hits on Google. Googling is not difficult, and should really be tried before posting a question here. There's so much information out there! Google is really your friend. :)

Comment: @anongoodnurse You could make an answer out of your comment. It could be a 5 letters long answer :)

Comment: @Remi.b - lol, really? I'll take you up on that one. Ah, the minimum has beaten me.

Comment: Yep. The size does not matter :) See [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/679754/top-10-shortest-accepted-answers) listing the shortest (typically two letters) accepted answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**FOXP2**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOXP2), aka Forkhead box protein P2.